# Show that "likely" is not truth functional

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Truth Functional (TF): Has a true/false value which can be completely determined by the truthfulness/falsefullness (?) of the input's values (got that?).

Question: Show that "It is likely that **__**" is not a truth functional operator (where the blank, the "input", is filled with a simple sentence with a true/false value).

We can prove "likely" is not TF by finding a single counterexample. How do we find a counterexample? For any simple sentence I create which has a true/false value, I already know if it's likely or not.

For example: $A \equiv$ "The Yankees won the world series", is True. It's also likely. Now I need another sentence, $B$, which is True, but is unlikely. Right? Would like explanation and example (or explanation by way of example). Thx.

Edit: P.S. You cannot answer by saying "likely" is a prediction which is not TF. I want to know *why* "likely" (or even any prediction) is not TF

Comment: If you choose a real number in the interval $[0,1]$ it is likely that this number will be irrational; I chose $1$ which is rational.

Comment: If you want something more... real life related: it is unlikely that anyone will be born with two faces. However there was this baby in India that was born like that not long ago.

Comment: What do you mean by likely? That means, what is the semantic meaning of $X \mapsto $ "it is likely that $P(X)$"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: What is $A$ equal to in your example (first comment)? Ditto second comment?

Comment: @dtldarek: "Likely" is not really defined. It's a regular english sentence, which is to be symbolized in logic. There is no specific probability which defines likely in this (I'm really hoping your comment wasn't rhetorical, here).

Comment: Jeff, $A\equi\text{ I will chose the number }1$. It is unlikely, but it is true. In the second one, $A\equiv\text{ Someone was born with two faces}$. **Highly** unlikely, but true nonetheless.

Comment: @Jeff The problem is that depending on the definition of "likely", it may be or might not be a TF. For example, if you define "likely" to depend on probability and you are free to pick your $\omega \in \Omega$, then this is like in Asaf's comment. However, I think that you could define "likely" the way, that *only always true* things can be likely. You cannot write a sound proof when you have no definition for some of the terms you use.

Comment: @Asaf: I think "I will choose the number $1$" (I think you meant 'choose', with two 'o's, not 'chose', which would have a different meaning),  does not have a true/false value. The sentence chosen must have a true/false value. The sentence "I chose the number $1$" has a true/false value (it's true). But then the operations yields: It is likely I chose the number $1$. In fact, it's a certainty. Unfortunately, I am still confused.

Comment: @Jeff I actually meant to say "I chose the number 1".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't go with finding a concrete counterexample; that seems to get us into a semantic morass that just detracts from the main matter.

Rather, I would say: By definition a "truth-functional operator" is one where the truth of "it is likely that $X$" depends *only* on whether "$X$" itself is true or not. Thus, if "likely" is a truth functional, then it must have a truth table, and *that truth table must explain everything about what "likely" means*.

"Likely" has only one argument, so there are only four different possible truth tables it could have:

```
  X   | X likely       X   | X likely      X   | X likely     X   | X likely
  ----+---------       ----+---------      ----+---------     ----+---------
  Yes | Yes            Yes | No            Yes | Yes          Yes | No
  No  | Yes            No  | Yes           No  | No           No  | No
```

But clearly neither of these matches any meaning that the word "likely" can have in English:

- The first one would mean that *everything* is likely.
- The second one would mean "it is likely that $X$" means the same as "$X$ is not the case".
- The third one would mean that "likely" means nothing at all; "it is likely that $X$" would just be a more verbose way to assert $X$ itself.
- The fourth one would mean that *nothing* is ever likely.

Since none of the possible truth tables work, "likely" does not have a truth table, and so it is not a truth-functional operator.

Comment: This is easy. The exact question says "Show that .... is not truth funcitonal" - it does not specify how to show it. My only concern is if the prof will accept this type of answer for a similar test question.

Comment: Why wouldn't he?

Comment: On a roll of a die, the odds of any particular side turning up are only one in six. But one always does. So nothing is ever likely. Your fourth table is correct!

Comment: @henning: Well, the book and the prof's class notes only showed counterexamples.

Comment: @FYI: I am told that she got all of the "prove <operator> is not TF" questions correct. Therefore the prof accepted this argument.